# Downloading content on app's first launch

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Working on an app which is relying heavily to download content (images and sound files) from the server while the app is launched for the first time. It may take awhile depending on the connection speed. Just wondering if that delay may cause my app to be rejected by AppStore review team? Though, be assured that I will display proper user feedback view to show progress indicator while the content is being downloaded. Kindly, share your valuable insights. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by Apple support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store" rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is show a first view in which you show the status of the download. Once the download is complete yo move to the firs controller of your app. You could save a variable to know that the initial download has already been done, and int future openings not go 
through the downloading view.

Comment: My real concern is regarding AppStore's review that would they approve this delay or not? I have pretty much implemented the download routine.

Comment: The Rio 2016 app has that behavior and is Recomended in the App Store. I think it is right indicating that content is being downloaded.